# Linode : Installing a working Jetty 9.x on DSL (Damn Small Linux)

Tags: linux, web-applications, java, linode, debian

I am exploring an option to deploy a java application with jetty on Linode.

While my endeavor to create a production grade system with the minimum resource utilization (so that scarce resources could be saved for actual customer request); I came across DSL (a Linux OS claiming to be the most lightweight version of debian).

The website for DSL is http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/

I tried going through the documents, but not able to determine if this can be replacement of full conventional Debian OS for hosting a Java application.

I am mainly concern about

1. if the OS would be able to handle a JVM crash and does not
   corrupt system beyond recoverable.
2. If it can provide enough OS
   level security to prevent a hacking attempt.